Upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 Youtube and Twitch videos not loading
I have performed the upgrade from Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 to 24.04.01 released yesterday via the update-manager -d command and the upgrade runned smoothly.
Nontheless when I opened my browser (tested on Firefox with no extensions, Chrome and Brave) whenever I try to watch any video in Youtube the video shows up, but the loading circle won't go away and the video never plays. On the otherhand in any Stream on Twitch the video shows up and plays at less than 0.1 frames per second.
I don't have the video issue in both Instagram nor Kick to give a few examples.
My GPU is an AMD Radeon RX6600XT which had no issues in 22.04.
What I tried with no luck:

Install / Reinstall ffmpeg
Install / Reinstall ubuntu-restrictive-extras
Install / Reinstall all codec libraries
Install / Reinstall my MESA drivers
Deactivated the Hardware Acceleration in my Browsers
Checked the DRM video reproduction
Cleaned cookies, cache, etc
Tried to repair dpkg and fix broken packages
Reinstall the browsers
Check my DNS in my /etc/resolv.conf which is set to 8.8.8.8
Restarted my PC in many ocations

My MESA drivers are currently:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
I don't know what else to look, I tried everything I found online.
¿Anyone else having this issue that solved in another way?
This is how the videos won't load

I just upgraded my Ubuntu Studio system to 24.04 and have run into this exact issue and worse -- none of my audio applications work.  To get YouTube videos to play I have to mute the audio, then hit play.  Once playing I unmute and the video keeps playing, but I have no sound.  I'm going through a PreSonus AudioBox to a pair of external speakers; don't have a built-in soundcard and my monitor doesn't have sound output.  Somehow the relationships between ALSA and Jack have changed completely and I'm at a loss.

I gave up, I restore my timeshift snapshot back into 22.04, I tried almost everything with no luck. This is my main PC that I use to work so I had to go back to an stable system. It's a shame that this kind of things happen.

I'm going to try a clean install of the 24.04 ISO (after backing all my crap up); that's the only thing I can think to do at this point.  Unfortunately I did the upgrade such that I can't revert to 22.04.

This seems to be a problem unique to those of us who upgraded from 22.04. Pulse audio is no longer the audio server, but is stays installed and screws everything up. Go into synaptic and remove the pulse audio server package. The pipewire package should already be installed. Reboot and have a great day.

Should I remove the pulseaudio before upgrading or once I'm at 24.04?
